# Why this strange behaviour in Python's print function?

Tags: python, formatting, string-formatting

```
print('\r2021529,"Aren\'t you something to admire?\r\'Cause your shine is somethin\' like a mirror",,')
```

gives this output:

```
'Cause your shine is somethin' like a mirror",,
```

What? Why is the front of the string being chopped off? Can it have something to do with the quotes?

Comment: print repr(string_from_above)

works fine!

Comment: What version of python do you use? When I execute this under 2.7.8 it prints everything.

Comment: >>> print('\r2021529,"Aren\'t you something to admire?\r\'Cause your shine is somethin\' like a mirror",,')

2021529,"Aren't you something to admire?
'Cause your shine is somethin' like a mirror",,

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I have the answer! \r is carriage return without newline. So this brings the caret back to the beginning of the line, at which point it overwrites the beginning of the string.

This is in the iPython Notebook version delivered with Anaconda.

Comment: It happens in the Python 2.7 that ships with OS X too.